# Why was my answer deleted by a moderator almost immediately?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, deleted-answers, moderators

I answered a question which is one of the top Google search results for a very misleading error message from the YouTub API with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58794204/396967):
[image: Deleted answer]

It was deleted as a duplicate almost immediately, however it is *not* a duplicate. I did answer other questions mentioning the same error message in a similar way, however I *did* tailor my answers to each question.

Since I couldn't vote to undelete I flagged the deleted question for moderator attention which was [declined](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/396967?showDeclined=true) with this rationale: "declined - if the content of both answers are similar, then it is a duplicate"

I disagree with both decisions and it feels there is no recourse. I think we should weigh helping our users higher than moderators enforcing not very well-defined rules. Very demoralizing!

Comment: I fail to see the tailoring compared to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54417656/youtube-api-v3-access-not-configured/58794050#58794050

Comment: "however I did tailor my answers to each question" ... rephrasing the same answer in a slightly different way is not what "tailoring the answer" means. **"moderators enforcing not very well-defined rules"** these rules _are_ very well defined, you just don't like them. **"Very demoralizing!"** let me guess, you feel unwelcomed?

Comment: @Tom Yes, indeed

Comment: SO has a reputation of being very hostile to (new) contributors and I've always felt this impression was overrated. Looks like I'll have to reconsider my position.

Comment: We have very high quality standards. If you consider that “hostile”, then you probably aren’t going to feel welcome here. This is very intentional. Note that it is not *personal*; our focus is on optimizing for high-quality content. Contributors are secondary, because this is not a social network. Moderators and curators do not consider how “new” a contributor is. We look only at the post itself. Posting multiple very similar answers is a red flag; it strongly suggests you should be closing/flagging the questions as duplicates instead. This centralizes the information, making it easier to find

Answer (score 23):

These answers all look very similar, and all 5 answers were posted within a 20 minutes time period:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A396967+%22automatically+disabled%22

It's likely that posting such similar content has tripped an automatic moderator flag (by a script used to detect users spamming duplicate answers).

You should consider voting to close questions as duplicates when the answers are same or very similar, even if the questions are slightly different.  If it's not immediately obvious that the resolution is the same, just drop a comment acknowledging that the question context may be different but the answer is the same.

Voting to close as duplicate helps reduce the fragmentation of information on site, and makes it easier to find the best answers when using the search.

Comment: And that is a reason to delete *all* my answers? IOW this community values rules higher than being helpful to our users that come here desperately searching for a fix to a incomprehensible error? That really leads me to question if I want to continue spending time contributing to this community.

Comment: It’s **more** helpful to users if there are just one or two good answers for the same issue, and N signposts leading there, rather than N answers. Remember that for every user posting a question, there may be a hundred users searching and finding their answers without needing to ask.